# Compilation Error Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++, macos, g++

I have a program that i am trying to compile from my project directory and haven't been able to wrap my head around the following error

My compilation command

```
g++ grades.cpp -o grades
```

I see the following error

**Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "tbb::task_scheduler_init::initialize(int, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      tbb::task_scheduler_init::task_scheduler_init(int, unsigned long) in grades-9c8d1a.o
  "tbb::task_scheduler_init::terminate()", referenced from:
      tbb::task_scheduler_init::~task_scheduler_init() in grades-9c8d1a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

I am not sure how to debug this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link against the tbb library you are tying to use,

```
g++ grades.cpp -o grades -ltbb
```